# Looking for a regex pattern between a range of 0.1 to 24. Need to allow for 2 decimal places

Tags: regex

I can't seem to get a regex to work that will allow a user to enter a float between the range of 0.1 to 24.  I need to allow 2 decimal places and it must be greater than 0 and less than 24.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?:(?:0\.[1-9]\d?)|1\d?(?:(?:\.\d\d?)?)|2[0-3]?(?:(?:\.\d\d?)?))$/
```

you can view it on  https://rubular.com/r/NezAGzQ3GPWWai

Comment: You fixed `0.05` for example, but are you assuming that whole integers, like `23` are not allowed?

Comment: Thaks. I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^(?:24\.00)|^(?:(?:(?:[0-9])|(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3]))\.\d\d?)
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/ssXFBI/1)**

Comment: I wonder if `0.05` is allowed?  And just `23` or any integer doesn't work without 1 or 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses!

I missed typed early and the acceptable range should be >= .01 and <= 24.  Below are other restrictions...

1. Leading zero is optional values less than 1
2. Decimal is optional but only allow 2 entries
3. 0, 0.0, 0.00, .0, .00 is not allowed